# Which is better to build credit score? Becoming an authorized user of another credit card or get a personal secured credit card?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, credit-score, credit-history, secured-credit-card

I am new to the US with a F-2(student dependent) visa, I want to have credit history and build credit score in the US. I think I have three options but don't know which is better to do or maybe better to do all of them?

1. Apply for an ITIN number, then get my personal unsecured(regular) credit card(I think it takes more than one month).
2. Apply for a secured credit card with $500-1000 deposit in few banks who don't need SSN/ITIN(like Bank of America) and get a secured credit card(I think it gonna take less than 1 week).

3- Become an authorized user of the credit card of another person like my wife, she has SSN and regular credit card.

Comment: Why not do both?

Comment: Option #1 is **four** steps: Apply for ITIN, wait, apply for CC. wait.

Comment: @RonJohn Sounds like an answer.

Comment: @RonJohn Your answer/comment is not clear.  You said you would pick #2 in both cases?  I suspect that it is a typo, and because it is a comment, it cannot be edited.  Please [post your answer as an answer, not a comment](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2298/10997).

Comment: @BenMiller-RememberMonica yeah I meant "If I were wise I would do **#3**."  The problem is that is is a really opinion-based comment.

Comment: You can interleave them. If I had a manly urge to immediately have my own CC, then I would do #2. **If I were wise** I would do #3.

Comment: @RonJohn [Opinion-based questions and answers are mostly acceptable here.](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2769/10997)  This question, after all, is looking for advice.  Just explain in your answer why you believe #3 is the wisest choice.  Without explaining why you think #3 is the wisest choice, your answer/comment is useless to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Being an authorized user on someone else's card *imputes* their credit score (as calculated just from that card), and it stays with you, just like any other card.

So, go with Option #3 while you're waiting for your ITIN.

Remember, though, that the wise person lives below their means, and pays the whole CC bill every period.  (I pay it off **at the end of every month** because it lets me associate *this* month's spending with *this* month's income.)

Thus, if your wife already has a good score, you might not see the burning need to get your own card.

Two more important tips are:

1. keep the statement balance below 20-30% of your credit limit (that ratio is called the *usage rate* and is used by the credit bureaus), and
2. you can (partly, even) pay on the CC bill early; that helps keep the usage rate low.  Computers make that easy to do.